# Multi site cron set up

Tags: 6, multi-sites, cron

I am doing some updates on existing drupal multi site set up and am unable to set up cron for subsites. Subsites are accessed in a different way (example.com/site1 example.com/site2 )
From browser accessing example.com/site1/cron.php runs the cron but its not running from crontab.

```
45 11 * * * /usr/bin/lynx -source http://example.com/site1/cron.php
45 11 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/site1/cron.php
45 11 * * * curl --silent --compressed http://example.com/site1/cron.php
```

Tried all these but its not triggering cron functions.

Comment: Are you getting some errors in the log? Did you try to run the cron.php as an anonymous user?

Comment: Yes, tried as anonymous user and it works fine in browser.

Comment: Check error log both in DB and on the server and post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not resolving the host names. Added an entry to `/etc/hosts` and it worked fine.